# Android 13 version Wifi Network disconnect not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-wifi, android-13

do we have any concrete answer for the WiFi network disconnection in Android Q and above versions?
I am facing issue in disconnecting a specific wifi network.

1. Whether Latest Android version supports direct disconnecting a wifi network?
2. From my search, looks like there are restrictions but not able to conclude.
3. If we can implement with our custom app, which is the best way?

Thanks.

My implementation is based on WifiNetworkSuggestion and WifiNetworkSpecifier for connection. For disconnection, i am using, on pressing the disconnect button of a Wifi, below function will get called.
`fun disconnectFromWifi() { connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback) }`

Comment: D/ConnectivityManager: StackLog: [android.net.ConnectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4863)] [com.example.wifistationmodescanner.stationmode.WifiDisconnectionCallbackHolder.disconnect(WifiDisconnectionCallbackHolder.kt:69)] [com.example.wifistationmodescanner.ui.stationmode.WifiStationModeFragment.onKnownNetworkButtonClicked(WifiStationModeFragment.kt:246)]

Comment: [com.example.wifistationmodescanner.ui.stationmode.adapter.WifiStationKnownNetworkAdapter$WifiStationViewHolder._init_$lambda$1(WifiStationKnownNetworkAdapter.kt:130)] [com.example.wifistationmodescanner.ui.stationmode.adapter.WifiStationKnownNetworkAdapter$WifiStationViewHolder.$r8$lambda$RYmaqHUzGaDIOTWsizBgnaia6w4(Unknown Source:0)]

Comment: [com.example.wifistationmodescanner.ui.stationmode.adapter.WifiStationKnownNetworkAdapter$WifiStationViewHolder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:4)] [android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7892)] [android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16219)] [android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7869)] [android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)] [android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30880)]
D/WifiDisconnectionCallbackHolder: Network Disconnection successful

Comment: I have to split the logs due to text size limit, i recently got from my Wifi Network disconnection request.